# How can you re-use or reconnect to a socket on the same port after disconnect?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server, port

I am doing a simple project involving a single server program and a single client program. It needs to check if the client is connected (from the server side) and vice-versa for the client.

When the client loses internet, the server needs to know it is disconnected. Then, the client needs to reconnect to the server when it regains internet

When the client loses internet and then regains internet, I can't reconnect using the same port.

I tried leaving the server listening and not shutting the socket down and that didn't work either. I have tried so many properties for the sockets in terms of re-using and also I tried the lingering stuff too.

I have seen that it can be stuck on some `TIME_WAIT` property set by the OS in the registry (in the case of Windows). My question, to restate, is to be able to use the same socket (more importantly the same port) to reconnect after the client lost and regained internet and to be still listening awaiting the reconnect.

Like I said, I can detect when it disconnects from the server-side and also on the client but when I try to reconnect using the same port and with the same socket or a restarted socket it still won't connect and it won't show up at all. Is there any suggestion to help fix this problem? I have been searching for a long time to figure out this problem.

Scenario:

1. Server is Listening
2. Client Connects to Server
3. Unplug Client from internet
4. Plug Client internet cable back in
5. Client automatically reconnects to server (Currently doesn't do this on same port)

TL;DR Lost and regain internet on client-server model, but can't use same socket and port to connect to server.

## CODE:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // This will stop the threads/connections and toggle the button back to its original state
        if (button2.Text == "Stop Listening")
        {

            listener.Close();
            stop = true;
            threadsActive = false;
            button2.Text = "Start Listening";
            textBox1.AppendText("Manually Closed Threads/Connections" + Environment.NewLine);

        }
        else
        {

            listenThread = new Thread(listenLoop);
            listenThread.IsBackground = true;
            status = new Thread(checkIfOnline);
            status.IsBackground = true;
            stop = false;
            threadsActive = true;
            button2.Text = "Stop Listening";
            localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("129.59.79.65"), 3000);
            listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listenThread.Start();
            status.Start();

        }

    }
```

====================================================

```
private void listenLoop()
    {

        try
        {

            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            textBox1.AppendText("Waiting for a client..." + Environment.NewLine);

            listener = listener.Accept();
            textBox1.AppendText("Client Connected!!" + Environment.NewLine);

            status.Start();

            while (!close)
            {

                if (stop)
                    return;
                // server connection loop

            }

            if(close)
                return;

        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {



        }

    }
```

====================================================

```
private void ResetSocket()
    {

        // stop all threads and connections
        stop = true;
        listener.Close();

        textBox1.AppendText("Attempting to kill threads..." + Environment.NewLine);
        //while (listenThread.IsAlive == true || status.IsAlive == true) { /*loop until the threads are killed*/ textBox1.AppendText("Closing Threads..."); }
        //listener.Close();
        threadsActive = false;

        textBox1.AppendText("All Threads/Connections Closed" + Environment.NewLine + "Restarting Threads/Connections..." + Environment.NewLine);

        // re-establish and start threads and connections again
        stop = false;
        listenThread = new Thread(listenLoop);
        listenThread.IsBackground = true;
        status = new Thread(checkIfOnline);
        status.IsBackground = true;
        threadsActive = true;
        localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("129.59.79.65"), 3000);
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listenThread.Start();
        status.Start();

        textBox1.AppendText("Threads/Connections Restarted Successfully" + Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code on how you are listening to the port? Normally you listen to the port and create a new socket whenever the client connects

Comment: have you read the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx
This code will allow you to handle reconnects just fine

Comment: Define "can't reconnect to the same port". What happens instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bind the client socket. Only the server port is important.

On the server side, just keep the listening socket listening. When the listening socket accepts a connection, it returns a *new* socket that represents that connection. When you detect a loss of connection, close the corresponding connection socket but leave the listening socket running.

On a side note, IMO the best way to detect a loss of connection is to periodically send data (in both directions).

I have a [TCP/IP .NET FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) on my blog. It is .NET, but the general concepts apply to any TCP/IP scenario.

Comment: I did what you said and it seemed to work. The functions I fixed are posted in this dropbox link (there may be other issues regarding other topics besides the ones mentioned in this question, but the parts I needed help on are fixed): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12438255/simple_server/functions.zip

Comment: hi, i know the post is old but I am wondering if binding the client socket is part of the problem or not. In my case it is preferable that the client socket is also binded to a specific port because i have different clients from the same machine trying to connect and need to distinguish them.

Comment: @snus74: You don't need to explicitly bind to a port in order to distinguish them. Once a connection is made, the OS will assign you a port, and you can use that to distinguish them.

Comment: I need the distinction before execution time, so the only way is assigning to a port. My question is whether this is a problem or not regarding port reuse when closing and reopening a connection

Comment: @snus74: There's a "reuse" option if you need to re-use specific ports; otherwise, you'd need to use a new port when binding a new socket. As a side note, ensure your code doesn't depend on specific ports in the ephemeral range.

Comment: When it returns a new socket that binds that connection, do you still send back on the same port?

Comment: Once a connection is established, you use that connection to send and receive your data. Your code doesn't send data to/from any specific ports; that's handled for you at the OS layer.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Stephen Cleary's terrific answer. After we create and bind it, the server starts to listen. Control enters the infinite loop. The client connects to server. If we now unplug the Internet, the client throws an exception, which returns us to the top of the infinite loop, where we await network connectivity before attempting to accept another connection.

```
private void ListenForIncomingHttpRequests()
{
    AwaitNetworkAvailability();

    // create
    var serverSocket = 
        new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // bind
    var localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port: 12000);
    serverSocket.Bind(localEndpoint);

    // listen
    serverSocket.Listen(backlog: 25);

    while (true)
    {
        AwaitNetworkAvailability();

        try
        {
            // client connects to the server
            using (var clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept())
            {
                ProcessServerSocketRequest(clientSocket);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to explain the principle clearly:
[Active and passive closing in an iterative server program](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=program-active-passive-closing-in-iterative-server)

> Program A initiates the active close, while Program B initiates the
> passive close. When a program calls the close socket function, the TCP
> protocol layer sends a segment known as FIN (FINish). When Program B
> receives the final acknowledgment segment, it knows that all data has
> been successfully transferred and that Program A has received and
> processed the FIN segment. The TCP protocol layer for Program B can
> then safely remove the resources that were occupied by the Program
> socket. The TCP protocol layer for Program A sends an acknowledgment
> to the FIN segment it received from Program B, but the Program A TCP
> protocol layer does not know whether that ACK segment arrived at the
> Program B TCP protocol layer. It must wait a reasonable amount of time
> to see whether the FIN segment from Program B is retransmitted,
> indicating that Program B never received the final ACK segment from
> Program A. In that case, Program A must be able to retransmit the
> final ACK segment. The Program A socket cannot be freed until this
> time period has elapsed. The time period is defined as twice the
> maximum segment life time, normally in the range of 1 to 4 minutes,
> depending on the TCP implementation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).