# How can listener reconnect client again

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm using the following example to receive XML messages. The client connects, sends a message, and then closes the connection. However, the listener only responds to the first connection. If the client reconnects after closing, nothing happens. The listener should therefore recognize when a client reconnects via the same port. I've tried quite a bit, but haven't got the desired result.

Does anyone see a solution to this example?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Socket_Server_Form
{
    public partial class Socket_Server : Form
    {
        private Thread n_server;        
        private Thread n_send_server;
        private TcpClient client;
        private TcpListener listener;
        private int port = 708;
        private string IP = "";
        private Socket socket;
        byte[] bufferReceive = new byte[4096];
        byte[] bufferSend = new byte[4096];        

        public Socket_Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        public void Server()
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listener.Start();
            try
            {
                socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtStatus.Text = "Client: " + socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(); });
                }
                while (true)
                {
                    int length = socket.Receive(bufferReceive);
                    if (length > 0)
                    {
                        txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtMessages.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferReceive); });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtStatus.Text = ("Error : " + ex.Message); });
            } 
            finally
            {
                listener.Stop();
                n_server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Server));
                n_server.IsBackground = true;
                n_server.Abort();

                txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtStatus.Text = ("Receiver stopped"); });

                if (socket != null)
                {                    
                    n_server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Server));
                    n_server.IsBackground = true;
                    n_server.Start();

                    txtMessages.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { txtStatus.Text = ("Receiver started, waitig for next connection..."); });
                }
            }
        }

        private void send()
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                bufferSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TxtSend.Text);
                socket.Send(bufferSend);
            }
            else
            {
                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    bufferSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtMessages.Text);
                    NetworkStream nts = client.GetStream();
                    if (nts.CanWrite)
                    {
                        nts.Write(bufferSend, 0, bufferSend.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            n_server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Server));
            n_server.IsBackground = true;
            n_server.Start();
            txtStatus.Text = "Receiver started";
        }

        private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            n_server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Server));
            n_server.IsBackground = true;
            n_server.Abort();
            txtStatus.Text = ("Receiver stopped");
        }        

        private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            n_send_server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(send));
            n_send_server.IsBackground = true;
            n_send_server.Start();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're wanting to receive this kind of text data, why not just use a simple HTTP server? Then you don't have to worry about this low level stuff.

Comment: `@ADyson` the message is xml sent on a TCP socket. I have no influence on the client structure. The messages are received and must be translated from XML to CSV and then saved. Everything already works. The only problem is, that when a client reconnect  again, the listenr not react. Do you think that could be solved better with an HTTP server?

Comment: Yes, because a HTTP server (assuming you just use a ready-made one and don't do anything crazy like attempt to write your own) knows when a request begins and ends, and carries on listening then for the next request. It just works. In .NET Core / 5 (and in newer versions of .NET) you can have a self-hosted HTTP server running within your application. But of course if you say you can't change the client which is connecting to your server, then it cannot work - they would have to also update to write it as a HTTP client instead of a raw TCP client.

Comment: The client's are deposit machines. unfortunately I have no influence on that. So it has to be a socket solution. Actually, not much is missing, the listener just doesn't notice when a cliant disconnecting.

Comment: With this example, is there any way to find out when the client the connection disconnected?

Comment: How does the client indicate that a message is finished? Do they simply disconnect? Or does the message have any kind of marker at the end of the data? (Or can you tell just because you always expect a specific closing XML tag, perhaps?)

Comment: I don't know if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922795/how-can-you-re-use-or-reconnect-to-a-socket-on-the-same-port-after-disconnect would help you as well

Comment: I see the behavior through a port listener.                                                       `Client connected
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RemoteMessage operation="Deposit"
Client disconnected`